# How can I show an icon in a WPF menu root item?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, icons

I'm designing an WPF application which needs to show menu items. In order to design a friendly user layout, I want to show an icon in each menu item, even in the root element. All menu items shows the icon correctly... except the root element of the menus. Is there any special way to do this?

I've tried putting the MenuItem.Icon tag on each Menu items including the root elements, but as I say, only the root items can't show icons. I'm using C# .Net Framework 4.7.2

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu Name="MnuMain" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Inicio">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="D:\Trabajo\Componentes\Proyectos\.NET\Librerias\WpfSecurity\Imagenes\32x32\green_flag.png" Visibility="Visible" /> <!-- This icon doesn't show in my aplication -->
            </MenuItem.Icon>
            <MenuItem Header="LogIn" Click="MenuItem_Click" Name="MnuLogIn">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="D:\Trabajo\Componentes\Proyectos\.NET\Librerias\WpfSecurity\Imagenes\32x32\green_unlock.png" /> <!-- This icon shows correctly in my aplication -->
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
```

How can I show icons on all the menu items, even in the root element?

[This is how my app show the menu... i want to add an icon to the "Inicio" element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgXIA.png)

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that my menu uses a Style to set some visibility definitions... it would be this the problem?... this is the Style Template.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- ************************* 
    * STYLE: MenuItem 
    ************************** -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightedBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF797878" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF505050" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidMenuFontBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightedText" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SolidMenuFontBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundBrush}" 
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col1" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col2" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!-- ContentPresenter to show an Icon if needed -->
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ContentSource="Icon" Width="20" Height="20"/>

                            <!-- Glyph is a checkmark if needed for a checkable menu -->
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="GlyphPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanelpath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,2 L0,4.8 L2.5,7.4 L7.1,2.8 L7.1,0 L2.5,4.6 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                            </Grid>

                            <!-- Content for the menu text etc -->
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
                               Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                               x:Name="HeaderHost" 
                               RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                               ContentSource="Header"/>

                            <!-- Content for the menu IGT -->
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" 
                               Margin="8,1,8,1" 
                               x:Name="IGTHost" 
                               ContentSource="InputGestureText" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                            <!-- Arrow drawn path which points to the next level of the menu -->
                            <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="ArrowPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"/>
                            </Grid>

                            <!-- The Popup is the body of the menu which expands down or across depending on the level of the item -->
                            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Focusable="false" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
                                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2,2,2,2">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Background="{DynamicResource MenuBackgroundBrush}">
                                        <!-- StackPanel holds children of the menu. This is set by IsItemsHost=True -->
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Background="{DynamicResource MenuBackgroundBrush}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <!-- These triggers re-configure the four arrangements of MenuItem to show different levels of menu via Role -->
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- Role = TopLevelHeader : this is the root menu item in a menu; the Popup expands down -->
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" TargetName="SubMenuPopup"/>
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" TargetName="Col0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" TargetName="Col3"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="GlyphPanel"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="IGTHost"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Role = TopLevelItem : this is a child menu item from the top level without any child items-->
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Role = SubMenuHeader : this is a child menu item which does not have children -->
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Role = SubMenuItem : this is a child menu item which has children-->
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" TargetName="SubMenuPopup"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- If no Icon is present the we collapse the Icon Content -->
                        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- The GlyphPanel contains the CheckMark -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="GlyphPanel"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Using the system colors for the Menu Highlight and IsEnabled-->
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedText}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SolidMenuFontBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: This should work. Have you checked the build action of the image source? It must be set to _Resource_.

Comment: Yes... well, at first i didn't add the image folder to the project, i have referenced all images directly over the path in my computer. But, to try your suggestion, i added the imagenes folder to my project and doed the reference by the relative path. In this case, the result is the same. I dont know if you saw the update of my question? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the information. Didn't get update notifications. I created an answer.

Comment: @BionicCode Yeah!!... this works fine!!... thanks alot for your patience and to share your experience. Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the root `MenuItem`'s icon visible either set this setter to `Visible` or remove it:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <!-- Role = TopLevelHeader : this is the root menu item in a menu; the Popup expands down -->
    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
        ...

        <!-- Remove this setter or set it to Visible -->
        <Setter TargetName="Icon" 
                Property="Visibility"
                Value="Visible" />
        ...
    </Trigger>
    ...
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Yeah!!... this works fine!!... thanks alot for your patience and to share your experience. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<MenuItem   Name="MainSettingsMenu">
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-20,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" Source="Image/gtext.png"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine, Rebuild the application or check the image which is not displaying.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu Name="MnuMain" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="Inicio">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Image/pr.png " />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    <MenuItem Header="LogIn"  Name="MnuLogIn">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Image/sys.png" />
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks... but i think that my problem is related to the Style Template... Have you seen my question update? Thanks!!